# Jetty ignores <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>

Tags: jsf, cookies, jsf-2, jetty, jsessionid

The first time I open my JSF website in a new private browser (i.e. with no previous cookies)...The website works fine.

If I close the browser down and then reopen in a new private browser (i.e. with no previous cookies) Jetty seems to append JSessionID to the URL of all my links.

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js;jsessionid=fsvm4xesy3ht1cu2yzoo080w"></script>
```

This seems to be causing issues with primefaces javascript components and I cannot click on radio buttons.

I am using

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1200</session-timeout>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Jetty. Using Jetty 8.1.15.v20140411 works fine.